# Android DDMS Logging reached URLs

Tags: android, ddms

If i turn off the internet connection on mobile, then i can see something like this in LogCat:

```
07-06 20:16:27.386: WARN/FRPC(31638): Error: java.net.UnknownHostException: api.myserver.com
```

But that's only the domain, not the whole URL and it logs it only when internet connection is not available.

Is there any way, how to see in LogCat which URLs are exactly called in the app?

Note: I'm connected to my real phone (Nexus S), not avd.

Comment: The reason it doesn't give you the full URL is because the connection has not been established, so the URL is never sent to the server.

Comment: Is this an app you've written or do you want to see generally what is trying to connect?

Comment: @Sean - it doesn't log the URL even when connection is successfully established
@Otra - generally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup a Proxy such as Fiddler2, your phone must be rooted and you will need the ASProxy app:

http://asproxy.sourceforge.net/

http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/version.asp
http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp
http://aurir.wordpress.com/2010/03/22/tutorial-getting-android-emulator-working-with-fiddler-http-proxy-tool/

Comment: Why Google doesn't allow you to change a network proxy without rooting your device is beyond me, I was delightfully surprised that iOS lets you do this without rooting.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `Log.d(TAG, "My url: " + fullURL);`

Comment: he isn't coding the app otherwise yes =)